# What if a boss requires supervision?

Tags: project-management, management

I work in a programming firm where the Projects manager always overrides set goals and milestones.

He is keen to undermine issues as "doable" more than recognizing that we set out to complete a plan prior to the work, instead of following the plan and only taking advantage of plan evolution where other goals do not get jeopardized.

For instance, in our latest project, we had agreed that it would take 6 weeks to roll out and publish to the users only then and after we had trained them, but we are only in the second week, and he is insisting that we deploy and let the users test whilst we develop.

I have a history with user perceptions when you let them down once, that perception can last the rest of a project, and that's what i try to avoid with clearly laid out plans.

Most of the time we can't override or question his decisions, because he is two levels above us, but we are on the ground and he lets us plan things then agrees, and only in the heat of the moment come to oppose the very things he agrees, and holds you to account. Above him, there is another manager, a more reasonable one who gives you platform to explain yourself.

Essentially, he doesn't seem to want to adhere to project plans and best practices, like at least following one plan: e.g. Waterfall Model of a project, or at least choose Code and Test and follow that one only. He mixes and this hurts projects.

Recently, I had called him out last year on one project, which he did not properly allocate backup resources that I had formally written to him in an email warning him three months before he replied that "i have people i can ask to do this job and they will do it in a manner of hours"; the live system broke down and lost all data, no backup system was in place, and he is silently pushing other people to take it up. This is the example of a catastrophe I don't want

**My Question**
Is there a way to manage such a boss or such traits and still be subordinate? Or this calls for unorthodox action?

I'm thinking to formally make this a complaint to the boss above him.

**Update**
I decided NOT to choose an answer, because there were two respectable points of view. I prefer Kilisi's response, and so do many who up-voted it. There are other answers along these lines, I commented beneath them on how their advice applied to me. Also, blankip provided a different take focusing on the attitude of the OP towards the manager, whilst I disagree, the argument does not lose its validity. I took both sides of the argument into consideration, and decided to cover my work, but at the same time remember my role, and not be delusional simply because I generally disagree with my manager. So anyone in a similar position may take their own route, the answers below helped a lot.

Comment: If he is 2 levels above you, why is he giving you orders instead of your boss?

Comment: @Jay We are able to interact with him, This is the structure <his manager> <him> - <team leader not necessarily our manager> - <us>, so he manages the projects and we are able to interact directly, or through the team leader...is this something bad?

Comment: It's not necessarily bad, but affects my answer! - Use your direct boss to play interference :)

Comment: You are considering complaining to a boss 3 levels up?  Just program and let the PM manage and mis-manage.

Comment: I can only go by what you have described, you know the company structure.  Normally you would have a boss that is directing things, not some other line manager interferring.

Comment: Thanks @Paparazzi, i hand't thought of the repercussions. I was reminded to remember "my role", and that is to program :). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Jay, yes, that is a bit of a strain since the team leader sometimes doesn't stand for what we decide, and eventually deal with the him directly.

Comment: Will someone please change that `you're` to `your`

Comment: Even though it may be hard to choose, you really should select one answer if it genuinely does answer your question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If he's giving you the orders in writing then your back is covered and his is squarely exposed. He's a bad project manager and unless something is very wrong with the company he will fall flat on his face eventually. Your major concern is not being his scapegoat.

Do whatever you are tasked to do (that's your role) and make sure everything that's stupid is in writing. If he orders something done verbally, send him an email outlining it for him to approve.

"Sorry boss, further to our meeting, can you clarify for me please. I need to roll out X immediately? I'm just preparing but thought I'd better make sure first."

All you need is a "Yes" answer to that and you're covered.

In terms of complaining higher up the food chain, it's not normally a good idea, because it's not something that's forgotten easily. I'd prefer to let him dig his own hole, rather than dig one for myself alongside his.

Comment: +1 Document, document, and then document some more.  You are also correct about not wanting to get the reputation as an "escalator".  That never goes away.

Comment: Thank you! This is good advice, and i don't want to be the "escalator", it is a huge burden indeed over the life of your career at a workplace. Always comes to bite you when people perceive you to do a bad job yourself later on. Thank you for reminding me "my role", i should remember this. Every time i think of successfully delivering projects even as a team member, i try to participate as a team partner who raises problems we may face as a team even if i may not be responsible for the problem later. I will remember this, to document where i might have felt otherwise, but still execute my duty

Comment: @PillingFine Always look out for #1, and be careful not to step in #2.  I might add, also document when things go right, or when you catch something BEFORE it becomes a problem, otherwise they will never know.  I got on one of my reports for NOT doing that.  "Oh, it was no big deal, I fixed it before the systems even hiccupped".  I told him to go back and add that to his report or nobody would ever know he saved the company from a mess.  document the good, the bad, the ugly the significant and the insignificant.

Comment: Of course document but don't do so in a way that makes it seem like you are trying to take him down with evidence.  I saw really no "issues" with the management in the question, and more with the OP.   Your last paragraph I completely agree with, especially for this guy.

Comment: @RichardU, thank you for the bit about documenting good work too.

Comment: @blankip Thanks for the first point about not being too "intent" on documenting for spite, i believe that's what you mean. However, in what way did you see problems, perhaps you can elaborate these in an answer?

Comment: Is there ever a situation where having the documentation does squat? When you get called in to HR and they are ready to walk you out of the building, does it ever save anyone's job to have proof you were asked to do all the things you got blamed for?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship You can be arbitrarily marched out for any reason whatsoever, documentation is useful when there is a dispute over facts, and yes, it has worked for me more than once, mostly in terms of disputes with clients, but in one case it got me paid off very well and given a chance to resign with an excellent reference rather than be sacked. They couldn't sack the manager because he was family.

Comment: I've never had a situation where anyone cared what the facts were :). They had already decided, and that was that.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship oh, it does wonders when HR turns bone-white when they see you've got the makings of a lawsuit.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship when big clients are involved it makes all the difference, and in the situation Richard pointed out. In my case it was a big client, they would have lost half their business in one shot.

Comment: Having a record of suing previous employers isn't great for your career. And it wouldn't apply in this situation anyway.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship It especially works when whoever you have to dispute is at the same level with you, but may be more trusted because of experience and time in the organisation. When the person is at a higher level than you, it might work when the rest of the organisation is skeptical of the manager (you may not know already), but will not publicly tell it, but when you bring your well documented case, they know when its the manager's history playing up and let you off the hook, possibly advising you how to deal with the manager. Again, it's not about putting the manager in the fire.

Comment: "You're major concern" -> Your major concern

Comment: The examples of workplaces where where documentation turns out to be "useful" sound like miserable places to work.

Comment: I will mention this.  If I was running a project - and I run many - and I found out that someone was documenting me because they thought I make moron decisions or to cover their ass - and spending company time documenting vs completing project work - this person might as well start interviewing elsewhere.  I probably won't fire them as long as they are competent but they will also never see a promotion.

Comment: But then if you make moronic decisions that means you both stupid and you are not listening to what people tell you, so it's unlikely you would find out what they are doing.

Comment: @blankip Also just by this, "spending company time documenting vs completing project work", for any future jobs I take I will make documentation a prerequisite to my work and taking that job. I have since realized that any manager that does not request me to do this is likely going to instructively change their decisions (without explanation), misrepresent you, and overwork you. The last company I worked in before this, documenting was more important than work, and it is the leading / dominating company in three major web applications in my country.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship It does help a lot when you live in a jurisdiction where HR/your boss has to justify your dismissal in front of a judge. Not so much in the US.

Answer (score 17):

He isn't unorthodox, he is calling the shots.  You as an underling have a skewed opinion based on your job and what you think.

Your project is a great example.  I have done the exact same things to a project about six months ago.  I went a few levels below me and required customer testing in the middle of the project.  The guys working on it were furious and I got a mountain of complaints and emails.

Guess what?  Didn't care.

Guess what else?  The project was ill conceived.  I got pushed into letting the group doing it.  After seeing what was developed in the alpha stages it was worse than I imagined.  So I needed to give our dev team and management a dose of reality.  We did customer testing and they hated every single last bit of it.

What is funny is that some developers - who sound a lot like you - complained and said that the only reason the customers didn't have more positive feedback is because the project wasn't done.  So we let a couple of developers finish their parts to get full feedback and customers basically said, "Didn't we tell you we hated the whole idea?  Why would I like it more in a finished or polished state?  Do you guys get it?"

Either way you have a job in the project.  And that job could change based on management's whim.  If you don't like that and are that vocal you might want to put in for a promotion or find another place to work.  If anything it is attitudes like yours that hurt projects more than managers like this.

As for your example of "not having a backup".  According to you, this manager really messed up.  But you don't really know.  It could have been a group of managers or even his boss that said OK we understand the risks, if we have a backup we have to spend this amount of time, it isn't worth it.  You could be right and it could be squarely on this one manager.  He made the same calculations.  Being wrong about something doesn't make him stupid, it just means he messed up.

This kind of example is like a developer sitting next to you telling you that you should write your code in a certain structure.   You think XYZ will be needed so you don't want to follow his advise.  XYZ aren't needed and it turns out that following his advise would have saved you a bit of time.  And then he writes an empirical email to you, your boss, and peers and shows the example of you not listening to him and wasting company time.  Your attitude is conveying that you are doing the exact same thing (not clear if you are or not).

**Verdict:  Be a person of power.  Instead of focusing on what this manager does wrong, focus on how to change his mind when you have an opinion.**  The things you brought up in your question mark yourself as a traitor/spy looking to take him down.  He works for your company.  Try to win him over.  If you feel that he is doing something wrong, try to influence him to do the right thing, not just bag on his idea.  This may lead to conversations about why he is making those decisions.  I am not trying to label the manager as "right" and you as "wrong".  We simply don't know and you should treat it that way.  What is clearly wrong is your approach and the results you have gotten with your approach.

**Note:**  The OP had comments before (deleted now) stating that I was a little harsh or did not understand.  I was not trying to come off that way.  There is nothing more than I like than a worker-bee and the OP sure seems like a worker-bee.  My second favorite feature in an employee is someone who disagrees.  Tension builds companies!  But the OP needs to realize that they need a mechanism to react to the management without "calling them out" or "documenting" things and showing stuff after the fact.  If I am running a project I want the dissension when you feel it, not months later proving you met a milestone I originally asked for.  I listen to pretty much everyone, especially devs working on the project.   I might say no to something initially but after something happens I might change my mind based on a conversation 3 weeks ago with an angry dev.  There is just a lot going on with big projects.  I am in upper management but not the top of the food chain - there are often things that are going to happen no matter what.  If my boss told me to get customer feedback (even if I disagreed), guess what you are doing the next two weeks?  Doesn't make me a dumbass nor does it mean I am not listening.  And for the OP - he seems to have a lot of good things going for him and feel that if he doesn't dramatically change how he deals with management, he will probably never progress how he wants.

Comment: Were your comments moderated off? I did not report them. Anyway, again, the edit you made is implying that i question his project approach decisions. That's not what I'm annoyed about. In my case, I'm reporting someone who overrides already team documented plans when he has already took part in agreeing to them. The complaint is on how this exposes goals of the project. If in the original plan (which he agrees) there is no room for him to make a drastic change to an aspect of a project, then regardless of being a boss, he becomes a risk to do so because planning is about avoiding this.

Comment: Intransparent decisions, things that are not communicated, foster a hostile work environment. When someone on the board decides something that makes everything worse and the people in the level below can not convince them (based on feedback from the people again below them), then the next step is to communicate this _down_ the food chain. Always, always, always make people understand the _why_ for your decisions and they will follow you everywhere. Try to protect them and fight against things that make their situation worse and they will protect you as well. And then go drink a beer with them.

Comment: I do not know what your project was like, but changing fundamental aspects which you had already planned with the team is a different matter. You talk about finding out that the project was ill conceived, If you were part of the conceptualisation then you failed both you and your team to communicate the path for your project. In my case, this is someone with whom we agree on fail-proof (as foreseeable) plans, taking into consideration aspects that need not be skipped to assure a given goal. For one to arbitrarily instruct such a measure "can" be skipped later on, is abject recipe for failure.

Comment: @PillingFine - big companies get big budget money to do XYZ.  There is often not a lot of manager input on changing XYZ at the beginning of the project.  So even if I think something will fail I am not a failure for not ditching the project right away.  I think you are thinking of projects as a house you are building and adding legos each day.   Some projects work like that, most don't.   You are saying the project will now fail because it is getting client feedback seems far fetched.  Maybe your "milestone" won't be hit... who cares!!  Think big picture - goal of company not small picture.

Comment: @blankip you keep dodging my explanations, your example in the XYZ scenario would be factored in as a foreseen change, the difference with my boss is he isn't justifying the change with some other plan that works anyhow, the manager chooses plans that open up risks that are otherwise closed by adhering to carefully made out plans, just to "do it" because it "can" be done. This is opportunist and "can" save money and supposed time, but also does exactly what we work hard to avoid as best practice employees in analysis and planning.

Comment: I am not dodging anything.  You keep saying that your boss is changing things and opening you up to risks.  The only thing you mentioned is the boss requiring customer feedback.  In my opinion that is not changing anything - maybe your milestones and PM crap - but he is not changing the essence of the project at all.  It seems like he is enhancing it.  Also by going far along the project timeline without customer feedback seems like the risk.  I think you are too stuck on timelines and deadlines - the main goal of a good project is too deliver best possible product.

Comment: +1, current software thinking best practice is to have working software available for UAT every couple-week sprint; basically he's telling you to do the right thing and you don't understand so you're sad.  It's why he gets paid the big bucks.

Comment: @mxyzplk - BINGO!  I can't imagine any of our devs even contemplating going off for months without getting feedback.  This guy acts like - leave me alone and finish this over the next 2 months so it is on time.  Holy crap!!  And its usually not the devs "at fault", it is the client UX designers and PMs that hand them over idiotic specs.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like he could probably coach folks better, but I always find it hilarious how everyone around here always thinks "that guy two levels above me who makes twice what I do totally doesn't know anything! I disagree with his decisions so he must be wrong!"  I find that... Statistically unlikely.

Comment: @mxyzplk - I am that guy.  They aren't usually wrong.  I agree with them most of the time.  But they usually don't understand that certain things just have to happen no matter how dumb they are.  I have been commended for halting useless projects... when I try to halt 80% but actually halt 30%.

Comment: Someone that insists in keeping up with a pre-arranged plan between all parties is not a "traitor". The role of the higher up is also protecting the underlings from the internal politics,  communicating and facilitating mediation with the other departments, not messing up with projects. You can bet I would find another job with a manager like this.

Comment: @mxyzplk That it's "best practice" doesn't validate the action of changing to that in the manner I have explained. It has advantages that you mention, but in this case we are moving from an existing system to this new, and the 6 week time was decided to give the user everything done by the existing system in stable shape, with basics of the new functionality in place. We had to avoid giving users yet another application with faults found in the old system.

Comment: Again, you keep implying that i'm questioning the manager's methods. This is false because that is influencing @mxyzplk too, I clearly asked consistency in approach and gave it as an example, of how changing between the Waterfall Model and Code and Test midway may have an negative on deliver-ability, taking an opportune decision that adversely affects the mission-criticals of the whole plan.

Comment: In case this gives you light in what I'm talking about: "I think you have to be clear whether you now want us to follow the project outline as carefully planned, or just wait to hear anything you say and just execute it without thought, because that instruction deviates immensely from the project outline we all have agreed on at the onset." This is an except from one communication we had with him, in response to something he insisted.

Comment: In fact, what everyone's answer said essentially is: if possible, ideally his changes should still appear as edits made by him in the document, not just visit offices and instruct. If he is not doing so, yet instructs contradictory to the fundamentals of that document, then I should be the one to document these decisions as instructed by him, because I will be the fool to follow instructions simply because its management, when a document is in place to the contrary, originally agreed also by him. Thus: "When a manager requires supervision" to respect project plans and not be opportunistic.

Comment: @PillingFine I've removed my downvote of this answer (originally because I thought the tone was harsh) because I now believe that you seriously need a huge reality check. It's not your manager's job to play secretary. It's not your managers job to "respect plans" and "not be opportunistic." I maintain that *perhaps* the manager should attempt to communicate better, but the more this thread continues, the more inclined I am to side with your manager. You are not engaging in bottom-up democracy. Provide input, but your manager makes the decisions. If you can't abide by this you should be fired.

Comment: @brian_o, "which decisions"? just because he is manager does not equip him to make "any" decision is my point. I gave an example of project plans as being like constitutions, the purpose (at least in my organization) is to avoid conflict of interest influencing later decision. Each of the plans we make bind each one of us to execute it as flexibly outlined. This manager's role is NOT to override it, even if he has the upper job. Its to facilitate sound planning of a project prior (including making major decisions), communicating them and aligning them to the goal of the company.

Comment: The role, contrary to what you say is to respect the plans like any of us and not be opportunistic too, however, being equipped to a greater degree with  influence which he can exercise unopposed in the planning phase. After this, the plan, including all flexible changes that can be made, becomes the authority, so that no one is exploited by the individual decisions of any other. Otherwise he ought to follow proper channel to update the formalise and let us understand that we are no longer officially bound to the original plan. Currently, we end up doin one thing, whilst document says another.

Comment: To the outside world, we seem to work with a plan, and yet his interjections and instructions come sometimes adverse to the plan itself, such that those instructions that have the capability to cause harm to some of the goals in the plan, will make the team look clumsy if these risks manifest. This is because to the other management, they look at the plan and ask why development would not have followed it, because these plans contain all covers to support company policy. I am more annoyed that he keeps pushing you to action his changes, just because he sees them doable, even if not documented.

Comment: You are not getting it.   I have told you if your attitude doesn't change you will never get promoted.  Would I love to have you as a dev on my teams?  For sure!  I love passionate people.  But you don't get the big picture.  #1 you should never be writing code that long that isn't field tested - do you trust the PMs and UX people that much?  #2 Things change and when you miss a "milestone" when things change no one blames you.  They will blame you if you miss the milestone because you are bitching about things changing too much.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that this manager may not be amendable to constructive criticism, but if you are interested in a non-adversarial approach you could attempt to schedule a short, 10-minute face-to-face meeting and outline your concerns privately.

- Acknowledge that he is the decision maker who may have access to information that you (the workers) don't know about
- Acknowledge that requirements can change after a plan has been made

But:

- You'd like him to acknowledge that at some level, too much thrashing can damage your company's ability to complete projects and satisfy customers
- You feel like your company is thrashing too much
- Give at least one concrete example of effort that was expended but wasted because a requirement shifted after the completion

It's your boss's job to decide what priorities are and when to cut losses. Sometimes the right thing to do is to discard completed work and shift directions. You might gently conclude that you either have a **performance problem** (too much waste due to thrashing requirements) or a **communication/morale problem** (the in-the-trenches programmers don't understand why their effort is being wasted/ignored).

Comment: This is a level headed approach i should keep in mind. It helps understand that you can try to get your argument across in a dignified manner, and with a goal to discuss further cohesion in future work between the manager and his team. I might take this route for the benefit it has to team and the organisation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Like the other answers, Document, document, and cover your ***.  Outline negatives in writting.

Alternately, forward everything to your direct boss.  Make your boss play the bad guy and play the politics, and give you marching orders.  Outline your concerns with your boss.  If your boss plays ball with the manager, and asks you to do the work, you are off the hook.

This option depends on your goals and culture.  If it would be better for your career to always please the manager, then keep doing so, and make sure he is aware of your concerns before you agree to carry out his commands.

Comment: Thank you! I like your last question, I am someone who who has a success minded approach. Even when i am not responsible for failure, i do not keep quiet, i play as a team member when it comes to the work itself, only to save the team problems, not to "not be responsible". But thank you, because i should do my duty to execute as per manager's instructions, but document if i feel there should have been another way.

Comment: I'm always a bit confused when people say document everything. From my experience, even with "documenting" it carries very little weight when defending yourself in a corporation. From my experience, if a manager is bad, he/she will simply say they told you otherwise and you'd still get knocked off for it. If you need to document stuff, then it is time to quit, in my opinion. Unless someone else got your back, it's very doubtful documenting will even work unless the person is honest to begin with.

Comment: @Dan; it all depends how bad it is... Sometimes documentation is just useful when someone 'doesn't remember' agreeing to something, and then having the documents to remind them and get something done.  Yes, if you are doing this all the time against your own boss, it's toxic and you should leave

Comment: @Dan in this case, i got it to mean i have to document "whenever i identify and alert him kindly of how he may be overriding a decision that may fail the project at some point", so that [if] that outcome does come as a result of his direct instruction which i have evidence of warning him "kindly", i do not have to throw tantrums, but show the emails of communication leading to the decision he made in spite of my logical warnings.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this guy has been with the company for a very long time. As such he delivered projects over and over again even though you consider his method to be unorthodox.

Pretend for a moment he screwed up like last time, all the data has been lost and he's quietly pushing it up himself. He's telling upper management that it's you guys fault and he's fixing it. Suddenly you jump up screaming about he's a bad manager and this is why. How is that going to make you look?

The best advice is to let him fail on himself, which probably will never happen, or simply find a new job and quit, leaving behind such negativity and hopefully going for a positive.

Comment: Good pick up! He has been in the small company a long time. When i was hired, i thought he recognized the experience i had garnered from my previous places, of modern approaches to systematic project roll outs, so at every turn i have tried to participate and assist if its for the good of the company. But i do not see application or opening up to any of these new methods. He wants someone who does it his way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rock the boat. When you see a concern report it up to your immediate supervisor via email so there's a record you informed them of a problem.

Never ever go above your bosses head. Engaging management above your pay grade will ultimately lead to resentment, bad reviews and eventual termination. Your supervisor will view it as backstabbing. What you seem to want to do is "pull rank". It's deadly for your career. If you hate the culture there, look for a new job. If you can't, for whatever reason, keep your head down, do what you are told, and make sure you document your concerns with your -immediate- supervisor. Don't copy VPs and the CEO. It's not your place to do this.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this is a level headed approach. I now am concerned about the culture of not sticking to documentation throughout the course of a project, and baiting to take opportune decisions, thus essentially making me dislike this culture as a whole. It's not good for career growth in the way I wish it to. I do not want to take another job yet, for the industry within which we supply our services is of keen interest to me, and I wish to explore more technologies in it. Hence I will take your advice to lay low, do as I'm told, assisting where allowed and documenting where we may not.

Comment: One thing about waterfall... When a project is done using that SDLC approach, very often you'll run into obstacles that require changes to the spec. The key there is to amend the documentation with the changes in appendices, or whatever. How this gets done is as variable as the organizations out there are. It's important to do but often falls by the wayside. In a lot of cases the documentation/spec ends up being ineffective. That's one reason a lot of coders prefer the agile approach. Unfortunately in a lot of ISO 9xxx standards driven organizations, waterfall is required by policy...

Comment: Your point is a very good one, because we by HR are held by this standard, whenever someone goes into disciplinary hearing for things such as systems downs etc, such strict approaches are asked by management who don't care why you skipped them, because its the requirement. As such, when someone comes in the middle of a Waterfall SDLC, tells you to deploy anyhow, and yet on hearing you will be question on this because you executed an undocumented step, you fall. The irritating thing is I always quote the project spec, and as a boss he overrides it and implicates your action as adverse to "work"

Comment: Idea! Instead of quoting the spec in a meeting, send your immediate supervisor the documentation revisions that his bosses' changes required. Then not only are you covering your butt, you are a team player :-) Do it with email so there's a record. Then you are beyond reproach.

Answer (score 1):

My Boss/CEO sounds a lot like your Boss, the difference is that he can see the work being built on a week by week bases, whereas your PM cannot.

Anyhow, I think there is a big problem with the way the project is being managed (I am a PM). It sounds like you guys have adopted the Waterfall approach, where you have a long list of requirements and promise to deliver it once they have all been done.

The problem that I am seeing here, is where your PM has to report progress to stakeholders but is then put in a situation where he has nothing to show to them, the pressure is then probably trickling down to you guys. Hence your current predicament.

If I were you, I would look into adopting Scrum, and mention the benefits to him. Plan your project in the following way:

1) Sit down with the PM at the start of the week and agree on what work needs to be delivered. Use the week to implement, test and deploy to staging, then at the start of the following week it is his job to report progress to the stakeholders. Once everyone is happy, deploy to production.

Keep on repeating this cycle until the whole product is developed.

Comment: You express the issue in better words than I did. As a young employee, i favor the modern methods, the company policies favor the more rigid ones though, this is what's just there and the reputation is old and proven by the owners for their clients. I always adhere to company policy or the document thus, since its what the company's risk and guarantee is measured on. Yet he puts pressure on us, without documenting it (essentially exposing us), instead of advocating the change at company level, and having us benefit from Agile/Scrum/Code&Test etc, with the company's blessing too. Thank you.

Comment: @PillingFine have you made him aware of the agile way of doing things, if not, mention it can benefit him and make the process smoother. If he rejects the idea, well you will then have no choice but to work under that style of management. I would look for a new job. Also, what type of company is it...start up, corporate etc?

Comment: Software development company, about 15 years, corporate because of the client base. Yes, the first week I was employed, I made note of gaps I thought existed, among them Agile, he did not shoot it down, but seemed not interested to seek to convince changing company policies, which I agreed with. However, I also noted we do not use any bug / version tracking application (I setup JIRA/Confluence for documentation, showed it's merits), this DID NOT need \ policy change, he actively shot it down. This could have cleared these disagreements, but he actively does not get involved in using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you seem to be aware that he can't measure progress without a UI to look at and he seems to want to keep the client engaged, development can take a long time and people get board.

With this in mind maybe you might want to drive UI first plans and include a point where the client can be involved sooner.  You bosses boss may be having his time pulled around by the client and passing it down to you (and almost certainly not maliciously).

It might be worth making time to check his views on the project (and many times throughout the project) as he might not understand what value building the foundations for the application will bring.  He may even decide he can't get enough money out of the client for that and may want you to take the quickest route to a delivery even though it will make support and further development more difficult (read expensive).

On the other hand if he is just unreasonable i'd start looking for a new job.

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't mind working with the client engaged from the onset. On the contrary, the manager in question almost always bases his decisons on whether something "can" be done, rather than whether doing it can affect other carefully planned aspects of a plan. That just is an example, where the original, laid out plan agreed with the customer in question, was to present after the sixth week, all of a sudden in the second week, the manager in spite of calls by us his team to take heed of the effect on customer perception if the prototype is not up to scratch.